# Winrm connection is not working for local DNS Admins for Windows Server 2016

Tags: java, powershell, windows-server-2016, winrm

I am using WinRM tool in Java to communicate and run PowerShell commands on Windows Server.
When I do this using Administrator account, everything is working fine.
But if I provide newly created user account who is under DnsAdmins security group, then I am seeing following exception:

```
Mar 04 11:27:53 **java.lang.RuntimeException**: failed task create
Mar 04 11:27:53 at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.RetryingProxyHandler.invokeWithRetry(RetryingProxyHandler.java:67)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.RetryingProxyHandler.invoke(RetryingProxyHandler.java:34)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.create(Unknown Source)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.WinRmClient.createShell(WinRmClient.java:344)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.winrm.WinRmTool.executeCommand(WinRmTool.java:283)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.winrm.WinRmTool.executePs(WinRmTool.java:299)
Mar 04 11:27:53 Caused by: **java.io.IOException: Authorization loop detected on Conduit** "{http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd}WinRmPort.http-conduit" on URL "http://x.x.x.x:5985/wsman" with realm "WSMAN"
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.detectAuthorizationLoop(HTTPConduit.java:1946)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.access$600(HTTPConduit.java:150)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.authorizationRetransmit(HTTPConduit.java:1526)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.asyncclient.AsyncHTTPConduit$AsyncWrappedOutputStream.authorizationRetransmit(AsyncHTTPConduit.java:821)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.processRetransmit(HTTPConduit.java:1461)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleRetransmits(HTTPConduit.java:1435)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1565)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1371)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.asyncclient.AsyncHTTPConduit$AsyncWrappedOutputStream.close(AsyncHTTPConduit.java:429)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
Mar 04 11:27:53 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
Mar 04 11:27:53 ... 90 more
```

**Note: Credentials provided are correct and the Windows server is configured with HTTP.**

Comment: Are you trying to run PowerShell on a Domain Controller?

Comment: Hi Mathias,
Powershell is already running on Domain Controller. I just want to execute the Powershell commands.

Comment: You need to be a local admin to use the default PowerShell WinRM endpoint, and DNS Admin != not a built-in admin on DCs. If you want help configuring a constrained endpoint on the DC that you can connect to using non-admin creds, please update the question with the actual details